# c++ while loops, using getline function

Tags: c++, xml, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

Ok so to start because people like to know, this is homework....

I am writing a C++ Program to convert a text file to XML (this is not where I need help)
I am having this issue.

I am writing a while loop to cycle through the companies in the txt file (up to 15) and at the end of each group it is marked with the words --END_MANAGER_DATA--. I am trying to write a while loop that will loop through the company's and finish looping when it reaches --END_MANAGER_DATA--. below is an example of the txt file

```
19936 WALKER KOLTON PORTLAND TN
HARMAN INTERNATIONAL INDUSTRIES INC
LUCENT TECHNOLOGIES INC
COMPUTER SCIENCES CORP
COMMUNICATIONS CORPORATION
--END_MANAGER_DATA--
```

this is the code I am trying to use.....

```
getline(inFile,company);
inFile.ignore();
while(company != "--END_MANAGER_DATA--"|| !inFile.eof())
{
    outputfile <<"\t\t\t <company> "<<company << "</company>"<<endl;
    getline(inFile,company);
    inFile.ignore();
}
```

this is not working....it just stays in the loop.... can someone offer advice as to a route I can take. I am not asking for you to finish my homework....just need a nudge in the right direction

Comment: this did not post properly....

Comment: tried to fix the file content, is that what you were tring to do?

Comment: I just fixed it...the first like is employee info... I get that to post to my output file properly in xml format. the remaining lines are the names of each company....

Comment: You omitted most of the important parts, such as the definitions of `getline`, `infile`, `company`.

Comment: ifstream inFile - used to open file for edit
getline is getting the line of each company from the txt file (inFile)
company is variable name used to store each company name from txt file

Comment: sorry this is the first time I posted here, and having issues posting code...

Comment: Yawn `||` instead of `&&` yawn

Comment: yep that ended the loop....but in your infinite arrogant wisdom you might have noticed the ignore function that was causing it to look over the first part of the while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string company = "";
while(company.compare("--END_MANAGER_DATA--") != 0 && !inFile.eof()) {
    getline(inFile, company);
    outFile << "\t\t\t <company> "<< company << "</company>" << endl;
    inFile.ignore();
}
```

Comment: lol spoke to soon. Loop ended at eof...but still wrote past end of manager data

Comment: firgured it out, the compare wasn't working due to the inFile.ignore(); it was ignoring the first - of end manager data.... THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 4):

The idiomatic way to read data is to put the `std::getline()` into the while loop's test condition rather like this:

```
std::string line;

while(std::getline(inFile, line) && line != "--END_MANAGER_DATA--")
{
    std::cout << "\t\t\t<company>" << line << "</company>" << '\n';
}
```

This works because the while will only proceed if there were no errors reading the line. Testing for `eof()` doesn't work because `eof()` doesn't happen until after the read has taken place and the read will only take place if no error condition already exists.

In your code you `ignore()` the first character of each line which is why, I think, you can never match "--END_MANAGER_DATA--".

Comment: Thank you, yes the ignore function was what the problem was.